# Unity problem with call api and set data after it

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a call to my Firebase database that retrieves data from a player, and then it sends this data to an object. (In this object there is a list containing the weapons).

Except that in another file, I call the function to retrieve the weapons in the list. This one is empty when the game starts, because the then is not passed yet.

I solved the problem by setting an isReady variable to true when the then is passed, and I put in a void Update() the call of the function on the list.

I don't think this is the right solution, and there must be a better one, do you have an idea ? I start on unity

Here is the code :

This method will search in the list.

```html
public void DisplayIfOwned()
    {
        if (GameObject.Find("PlayerManager").GetComponent<GetDataSoldier>().soldier.weaponsList.Contains(id)) weapon.SetActive(true);
        else weapon.SetActive(false);
    }
```

This method calls api to retrieve the player.

```html
 public void FillSoldierData()
    {
        RestClient.Get<Soldier>("https://minisoldiers-fdd66.firebaseio.com/Soldiers/" + SoldierCreation.soldierName + ".json")
            .Then(response =>
            {
                soldier = response;
                UpdateSoldier();
                isReady = true;
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should provide more clear information, I needed to make assumptions of how exactly you did things. Don't hesitate to add more code snippets, it's very helpful :)

If my assumptions are correct though, then why not just call `DisplayIfOwned` method directly inside `Then(...`? You said you're doing that in `Update`, so you surely have class level reference that has access to that method.

If it's done in some other way, then this might be what you want: [Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=net-5.0)

Comment: I've already tried, I have to run it in static, but then I get errors, like the class IDs are not accessible etc....
But yes the simplest way would be to call this method outside the class